# Basic program wont compile

Tags: python, wxpython, pycharm, mapnik

I'M using pycharm (python) (and mapnik)on windows 7, I just wanted to test  if everything is in place after installation. I used an example from the net here is it , and I have a frame error. Could it be an installation problem ? compiler ?? I'M very new to python. thanks in advance for your time.

```
"""
This is a simple wxPython application demonstrates how to
integrate mapnik, it do nothing but draw the map from the World Poplulation XML
example:
https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/GettingStartedInXML

Victor Lin. (bornstub@gmail.com)
Blog http://blog.ez2learn.com

"""

import mapnik
import wx


class Frame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, size=(800, 500) ,*args, **kwargs)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.onPaint)

            self.mapfile = "population.xml"
            self.width = 800
            self.height = 500
            self.createMap()
            self.drawBmp()

        def createMap(self):
            """Create mapnik object

            """
            self.map = mapnik.Map(self.width, self.height)
            mapnik.load_map(self.map, self.mapfile)
            bbox = mapnik.Envelope(mapnik.Coord(-180.0, -75.0), mapnik.Coord(180.0, 90.0))
            self.map.zoom_to_box(bbox)

        def drawBmp(self):
            """Draw map to Bitmap object

            """
            # create a Image32 object
            image = mapnik.Image(self.width, self.height)
            # render map to Image32 object
            mapnik.render(self.map, image)
            # load raw data from Image32 to bitmap
            self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromBufferRGBA(self.width, self.height, image.tostring())

        def onPaint(self, event):
            dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
            memoryDC = wx.MemoryDC(self.bmp)
            # draw map to dc
            dc.Blit(0, 0, self.width, self.height, memoryDC, 0, 0)

        if __name__ == '__main__':

            app = wx.App()
        frame = frame(None, title="wxPython Mapnik Demo")
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

here is the error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/example.py", line 16, in <module>
    class Frame(wx.Frame):
  File "C:/Python27/example.py", line 56, in Frame
    frame = frame(None, title="wxPython Mapnik Demo")
NameError: name 'frame' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You're calling a function called `frame`.  `frame` is not defined.  Were you expecting it to be?  (maybe you meant `Frame`?)  Python is a case-sensitive language, like most.

Comment: Which Frame ? there are many on the program

Comment: You made a class called `Frame` that subclasses `wx.Frame`.  Then you try to instantiate it but you've misspelled it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems with your code. This line is incorrect:

```
frame = frame(None, title="wxPython Mapnik Demo")
```

It should be:

```
frame = Frame(None, title="wxPython Mapnik Demo")
```

The reason is that the class name is `Frame` (not the capital **F**) and you want to instantiate that class to run the program. Also note that the line `if __name__ == '__main__':` is incorrectly indented. The following complete example should work:

```
import mapnik
import wx


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, size=(800, 500) ,*args, **kwargs)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.onPaint)

        self.mapfile = "population.xml"
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 500
        self.createMap()
        self.drawBmp()

    def createMap(self):
        """Create mapnik object

        """
        self.map = mapnik.Map(self.width, self.height)
        mapnik.load_map(self.map, self.mapfile)
        bbox = mapnik.Envelope(mapnik.Coord(-180.0, -75.0), mapnik.Coord(180.0, 90.0))
        self.map.zoom_to_box(bbox)

    def drawBmp(self):
        """Draw map to Bitmap object

        """
        # create a Image32 object
        image = mapnik.Image(self.width, self.height)
        # render map to Image32 object
        mapnik.render(self.map, image)
        # load raw data from Image32 to bitmap
        self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromBufferRGBA(self.width, self.height, image.tostring())

    def onPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        memoryDC = wx.MemoryDC(self.bmp)
        # draw map to dc
        dc.Blit(0, 0, self.width, self.height, memoryDC, 0, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame(None, title="wxPython Mapnik Demo")WAS WRONG
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is getting g better, I GET a different error:

```
    C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Python27/text.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/text.py", line 45, in <module>
    frame = Frame(None, title="wxPython Mapnik Demo")
  File "C:/Python27/text.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.createMap()
  File "C:/Python27/text.py", line 21, in createMap
    mapnik.load_map(self.map, self.mapfile)
RuntimeError: Could not load map file: File does not exist       of 'population.xml'
```

Now what is the population.xml file ??